# Auto Align flow chart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts, visio, flowchart

Having a flowchart in Excel, Need to Automatically align it beautifully like we can do in Visio. Is there any code available for doing this in Excel?

Thanks.

I have written a vba code, But it is not giving beautiful result as in Visio

```
Sub auto_align()
    On Error Resume Next

    'Compile the diagram
    Call Compiler

    'Clear array values
    For i = 0 To 99
        numberofchildnodes(i) = 0
        numberofnodesineachrow(i) = 0
        listofnodes(i) = ""
        nodeindexarray(i) = 0
        parentnodearray(i) = 0
        rownumberarray(i) = 0
        columnnumberarray(i) = 0
        numberofnodesineachrowarray(i) = 0
    Next

   'Get amount of space that must be given in the diagram between each nodes
   rowspac = InputBox("Enter the space between rows, usually 100", "Test Modelling Tool")
   colspac = InputBox("Enter the space between adjacent nodes, usually 200", "Test Modelling Tool")

  'Find the listof nodes
  i = 2
  Do While Sheet6.Cells(1, i) <> ""

    listofnodes(i - 2) = Sheet6.Cells(1, i)
    i = i + 1

  Loop
  'Find the number of nodes
    noofnodes = i - 2
    orignoofnodes = noofnodes

  'Find the begining node
    For i = 2 To noofnodes + 1

    b = False
    E = False

        j = 2
        Do While Sheet6.Cells(j, 1) <> ""

            If Sheet6.Cells(j, i) = "B" Then
                b = True
            End If
            If Sheet6.Cells(j, i) = "E" Then
                E = True
            End If

            j = j + 1

        Loop

        If b = True And E = False Then

            strt_node = Sheet6.Cells(1, i)
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    'Initialize values for start node
    For i = 0 To noofnodes - 1

        If listofnodes(i) = strt_node Then
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    parentnodearray(i) = 0
    nodeindexarray(i) = 1
    rownumberarray(i) = 1
    columnnumberarray(i) = 1

    nodeindex = 1

    'Call row order algorithm

    'Initialize row number and column number
    r = 1
    cc = 1
    dumnod = 1
    'Loop until all the nodes has row number updated
    Do

        'Traverse through all the nodes
        For i = 0 To noofnodes - 1

            'If row number matches the exiting row number, update the row number for childs
            If rownumberarray(i) = r Then
                Call roworderalg(listofnodes(i))
            End If

        Next

        'Increment the row
        r = r + 1
        'reinitialize column number
        cc = 1

        'Check if row number updated for all the nodes
        rowupdatedforallnodes = True
        For i = 0 To noofnodes - 1
            If rownumberarray(i) = 0 Then
                rowupdatedforallnodes = False
            End If
        Next

        'Sort all the array inorder to maintain the order of calling the nodes in each row
        Call BubbleSort

    Loop While rowupdatedforallnodes = False

    'Find the number of rows
    r = rownumberarray(0)
    For i = 0 To noofnodes - 1

        If rownumberarray(i) > r Then

            r = rownumberarray(i)

        End If

    Next

    'From last row minus 1 row to 1st row
    i = r - 1
    Do

        For j = 0 To noofnodes - 1
            'if a node falls in given row number
            If rownumberarray(j) = i Then
                'update the column number as sum of child nodes column number divided by number of child nodes
                columnnumberarray(j) = findcolumnnumberofparent(j)

            End If

        Next
    i = i - 1
    Loop While i <> 0


    i = 2
    Do While Sheet6.Cells(1, i) <> ""
        'Move all the nodes in the diagram according to row and column position which is obtained by multiplying the space factor obtained from the user
        x = findnumberofnode(Sheet6.Cells(1, i))
        Sheet1.Shapes(Sheet6.Cells(1, i)).Top = rownumberarray(x) * rowspac
        Sheet1.Shapes(Sheet6.Cells(1, i)).Left = columnnumberarray(x) * colspac

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    'Reroute all the connectors to ensure there is no intersection between connectors
    i = 2
    Do While Sheet6.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

        Sheet1.Shapes(Sheet6.Cells(i, 1)).RerouteConnections
        i = i + 1

    Loop
    Sheet1.Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?...

Comment: There are alignment options that you can use. Just select the objects you want to align and click Format in the menu, the Align option should be there. Well, assuming you're using Excel 2013. Aligning shapes in Excel sucks, though.

Comment: I mean i am trying to do this using VBA. like a tool kind of thing

Comment: I have written a VBA code that makes auto alignment. But it is not that good looking

Comment: @Yuvaraj Share your code, this is a website for helping with poor code, not writing you one from scratch

Comment: Have added the code